# Distance transform with Manhattan distance - Python / NumPy / SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance

I would like to generate a 2d Array like this using Python and Numpy:

```
[
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3],
  [2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1],
  [4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2]
]
```

Pretty much the the numbers spread left and right starting from the zeros. This matrix allows to see the distance of any point to the closest zero. I thought this matrix was common, but I couldn't found anything on the web, even its name. If you have a code to efficiently generate such a matrix or know at least how it's called, please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: what did you come up with?

Comment: What have you tried?  You might start with something that starts with the index location of one of the zeros and construct distance using the index values to all other points.  If you can do it for one zero, do it for all of them, and then take the minimum at each location...  That would be a suggested algorithm

Comment: Here you'll find an algorithm based on BFS: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/distance-nearest-cell-1-binary-matrix/amp/. It's much quicker than the brute force

Comment: @BNilsou Your comment is not related to OP ! delete it.

Comment: Thank you @BNilsou for the link. Seems pretty fast. Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: @TomLamensia So, as input parameters, what do you have? Is it a binary image of 0s and 1s?

Comment: @Divakar I have a matrix of 0 and 1, with the ones representing where I placed the 0s in the example I posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one with [`Scipy cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def bwdist_manhattan(a, seedval=1):
    seed_mask = a==seedval
    z = np.argwhere(seed_mask)
    nz = np.argwhere(~seed_mask)

    out = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=int)
    out[tuple(nz.T)] = cdist(z, nz, 'cityblock').min(0).astype(int)
    return out
```

In MATLAB, it's called [`Distance transform of binary image`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html), hence a derivative name is given here.

Sample run -

```
In [60]: a # input binary image with 1s at "seed" positions
Out[60]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [61]: bwdist_manhattan(a)
Out[61]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code and info, works perfectly!