# Python: distance from index to 1s in binary mask

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a binary mask like this:

```
X = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I have a certain index in this array and want to compute the distance from that index to the closest `1` in the mask. If there's already a `1` at that index, the distance should be zero.
Examples (assuming Manhattan distance):

```
distance(X, idx=(0, 5)) == 0 # already is a 1 -> distance is zero
distance(X, idx=(1, 2)) == 2 # second row, third column
distance(X, idx=(0, 0)) == 5 # upper left corner
```

Is there already existing functionality like this in Python/NumPy/SciPy? Both Euclidian and Manhattan distance would be fine.
I'd prefer to avoid computing distances for the entire matrix (as that is pretty big in my case), and only get the distance for my one index.

Comment: What distance? Manhattan? Euclidean?

Comment: `I have an index in this array` what do you mean?

Comment: You mean something like a [distance transform?](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html)

Comment: IIUC [`For manhattan one`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59998706/), use `bwdist_manhattan(X)[0,5]` and so on. That uses `cdist`, so you can simply change the distance metric there for euclidean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one for `manhattan` distance metric for one entry -

```
def bwdist_manhattan_single_entry(X, idx):
    nz = np.argwhere(X==1)
    return np.abs((idx-nz).sum(1)).min()
```

Sample run -

```
In [143]: bwdist_manhattan_single_entry(X, idx=(0,5))
Out[143]: 0

In [144]: bwdist_manhattan_single_entry(X, idx=(1,2))
Out[144]: 2

In [145]: bwdist_manhattan_single_entry(X, idx=(0,0))
Out[145]: 5
```

Optimize further on performance by extracting the boudary elements only off the blobs of `1s` -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion

def bwdist_manhattan_single_entry_v2(X, idx):
    k = np.ones((3,3),dtype=int)
    nz = np.argwhere((X==1) & (~binary_erosion(X,k,border_value=1)))
    return np.abs((idx-nz).sum(1)).min()
```

Number of elements in `nz` with this method would be smaller number than the earlier one, hence it improves.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_cdt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_cdt.html) to compute the "taxicab" (Manhattan) distance transform:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.morphology

x = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
d = scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_cdt(1 - x, 'taxicab')
print(d[0, 5])
# 0
print(d[1, 2])
# 2
print(d[0, 0])
# 5
```

Comment: Looks good! Is there a way to avoid computing the distances for the entire matrix `x`? My matrix is pretty big, and I just need the distance for exactly one index, so in theory the algorithm could stop early.

Comment: @knub Ahh I see, I assumed you wanted the whole map... No, I don't think that functionality is provided as such, you may be better using something like [Divakar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60339020/1782792) (in that case, you may at least save the result of `np.argwhere` if you want to compute the distance for a few points instead of a single one).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
def Manhattan_distance(X, idx):
    dist = min([ abs(i-idx[0]) + abs(j-idx[1]) for i, row in enumerate(X) for j, val in enumerate(X[i]) if val == 1])
    return dist
```

Thanks.